# Set User as Authenticated from WebAPI custom Middleware

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, oauth-2.0, asp.net-identity

I am learning to implement new custom middle ware(external login) in WebApi to authenticate user. I used empty template to learn what is actually going.

I got some good articles and external login custom middleware providers links to help me to achieve this.

1. http://bitoftech.net/2014/08/11/asp-net-web-api-2-external-logins-social-logins-facebook-google-angularjs-app/
2. https://www.simple-talk.com/dotnet/net-framework/creating-custom-oauth-middleware-for-mvc-5/
3. https://github.com/TerribleDev/OwinOAuthProviders
4. https://katanaproject.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#README

Based on these articles i finished custom middle ware for Github and successfully authenticated the user.

Now i need to understand how the webapi identity system authenticated the user and how the external claims are saved for this. So after successful login from third party I just created claims and call SignIn method.

Up to this all working correctly.

But after this i tried to access any protected resource using the access token (which is external access token) i got Unauthorized only. I assumed that since i am not registering the user to local database i can use the same external access token to use the resource.

I tried 2 ways. First, in the ExternalLogin  method itself, i redirected to protected resource after signin. Next i tried with rest-client.

**My Auth Configuration Code:**

```
[assembly: OwinStartup(typeof(CustomExternalLogin.Startup))]
namespace CustomExternalLogin
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            // Enable the application to use a cookie to store information for the signed in user
            // and to use a cookie to temporarily store information about a user logging in with a third party login provider
            app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions());
            app.UseExternalSignInCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);

            //Use Git authentication
            app.UseGitAuthentication("myclientid", "myclientsecret");
        }
    }
}
```

**My Controller Code**

```
    [Authorize]
    [RoutePrefix("api/Account")]
    public class AccountController : ApiController
    {
        [OverrideAuthorization]
        [HostAuthentication(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie)]
        [AllowAnonymous]
        [Route("ExternalLogin", Name ="ExternalLogin")]
        public async Task<IHttpActionResult> GetExternalLogin(string provider, string error = null)
        {
            string redirectUri = string.Empty;

            //Check any error and return
            if(error != null)
            {
                return BadRequest(Uri.EscapeDataString(error));
            }

            //if not current user is authenticated return challengeresult so that middleware continue for external authentication

            if (!User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
            {
                return new ChallengeResult(provider, this);
            }

            ClaimsIdentity externalIdentity = User.Identity as ClaimsIdentity;
            Claim providerClaim = externalIdentity.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier);
            Claim userClaim = externalIdentity.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.Name);

            string token = externalIdentity.FindFirstValue("ExternalAccessToken");
            IEnumerable<Claim> claims = new List<Claim>
            {
                new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, providerClaim.Value, null, providerClaim.Issuer),
                new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, userClaim.Value, null, userClaim.Issuer)

            };

            ClaimsIdentity identity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, OAuthDefaults.AuthenticationType);
            Authentication.SignIn(identity);

            Uri currentUri = Request.RequestUri;
            string home = currentUri.Scheme + Uri.SchemeDelimiter + currentUri.Authority + currentUri.Segments[0] + currentUri.Segments[1] + "Home/User?access_token=Bearer " + token  ;
            return Redirect(home);
        }

        #region Helpers
        private IAuthenticationManager Authentication
        {
            get { return Request.GetOwinContext().Authentication; }
        }
        #endregion
    }
}
```

My Protected Resource Code:

```
[Authorize]
[Route("User", Name ="User")]
public string GetUser()
{
    var authentication = Request.GetOwinContext().Authentication;

    return "Welcome " + User.Identity.Name;
}
```

Please help me to find where i missed

**Edit 1:**

I got the Current Issue. I tried to access with External Token. WebAPI Authorize verify the token with local so it always failed. So the solution is to create local access token and i am done. Working fine.

But currently i am checking why Authentication.Signin() method didn't create token for me?

Comment: In your Startup.cs, have you tried setting your default sign in middleware like this: `app.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);`? This should be the first line there.

Comment: @juunas now i tried by adding this line as first line. But still same. I think this is default as "Cookies:. After Authentication.Signin when i check signin claims authentication type is "Bearer" so any other configuration for bearer token

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i got it. From my edit, we can understand that local token is needed to authenticate users. For this we can use Authentication.Signin()  method.

**Option 1: Using Authentication.Signin()**

The main point here is this Authentication uses cookies to save information and bearer token to authenticate user. So we need to include the following lines in auth config

```
public static OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions OAuthOptions { get; private set; }


    OAuthOptions = new OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions
    {
        Provider = new ApplicationOAuthProvider(PublicClientId),
        AuthorizeEndpointPath = new PathString("/api/Account/ExternalLogin"),
        AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(14),
        // In production mode set AllowInsecureHttp = false
        AllowInsecureHttp = true
    };


    // Enable the application to use bearer tokens to authenticate users
    app.UseOAuthBearerTokens(OAuthOptions);
```

Now token is generated and authenticated successfully. The disadvantage of this method is, it always returns the token along with with the url. For pure api development better to return json etc.

**Option 2: Generate Local token and return as object**

Here we can simply create a local token and return as object like we want. For this we can use OAuthBearerAuthenticationOptions.

Need to add the following code in auth config

```
public static OAuthBearerAuthenticationOptions OAuthBearerOptions { get; private set; }

    OAuthBearerOptions = new OAuthBearerAuthenticationOptions();

    app.UseOAuthBearerAuthentication(OAuthBearerOptions);
```

After this, we can create a helper method to create local token. This method is already explainedand can found in the following article Step 9.

http://bitoftech.net/2014/08/11/asp-net-web-api-2-external-logins-social-logins-facebook-google-angularjs-app/

Now i am fine.If any of my understanding is wrong please explain